# SQL Server binary(n) returned to VB.NET as byte() - How to convert to Int without specifying array size first?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, vb.net, bitwise-operators

I'm storing a flag in SQL Server as `binary(n)` (currently n=2 but in the future is may grow). I use it to do bitwise and to check if it contains a specific value both in SQL Server and in VB.NET.

The flags are stored in an enum in the VB code:

```
Enum LocState
    Collection = 4096
    Sortable = 8192
    Synced = 16384
    Unsynced = 1 Or Sortable Or Collection
    ForSale = 2 Or Synced Or Sortable Or Collection
    Stockroom = 4 Or Synced Or Sortable
    ...
End Enum
```

I can perform the comparison in T-SQL using an interpolated string:

```
$"SELECT * FROM Inventory_Locations WHERE State & {LocState.Synced:D}>0;"
```

But when I need to return the value (State) to VB, it comes back as a byte array, and I can't perform the bitwise operators on that.

```
dim locRecord as DataTable=GetTable("SELECT State from Inventory_Locations;")
dim isStock = locRecord("State") & LocState.Stockroom > 0  'Returns error
```

I saw that the preferred method is to use `BitConverter`, but it looks like you have to use a different method based on the size of the byte array (also the `byte()` comes back Big-endian and VB.NET evaluates it as little-endian)

Is there a function to convert a byte array of indeterminate size to an integer? Or to another format that can do bitwise comparisons? Or is it best to write a helper function to catch these, reverse them, check the size, and apply the correct `BitConverter` method?

Comment: No answering the question I know, but these really makes me think you're inventing your own problem.  Wouldn't make things easier to create a table in your DB for LocState, then use FK relationships rather than trying to flit around with enums?

Comment: Good points. I wouldn't use a FK relationship because I want to be able to filter on Synced or Sortable or Stockroom and have them all return the Stockroom value. The bitwise operators give me the flexibility to have these categories without locking them into fields. Also I chose enums because I need to access these values from both SQL and the code (comboboxes etc) and I thought this might be simplest. I may have been wrong there :)

Comment: If you're storing two bytes anyway then why not just use `smallint` in the first place? If your `Enum` is type `Integer`, which is the default, then why not just use `int` in the database? Do you really need to scrimp and scrounge a few bytes here and there?

Comment: @jmcilhinney that's a good reality check. It's just habit to keep my programs tiny, but you're right that storing it as int would solve my problem for very little cost

Comment: @Scott You may be interested in the [FlagsAttribute attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute) of Enum.